# why php notice is not getting ignored?

Tags: php

I have been adding at the top of my wp-config.php the following to switch off php logger but won't take any effect on it. Is there something else what I should do?

```
error_reporting(0);
@ini_set(‘display_errors’, 0);
```

Comment: Check if you have WP_DEBUG to false in wp-config.php.

Comment: Your single quotes are no single quotes. Use `'` instead...

Comment: Yes I know. However in my code I have been using the single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Also in `wp-config.php`, set the [`WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY) constant to `FALSE`.

Snippet from [`wp-includes/default-constants.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/default-constants.php):

```
// Add define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', null); to wp-config.php use the globally configured setting for
// display_errors and not force errors to be displayed. Use false to force display_errors off.
if ( !defined('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY') )
    define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

Comment: tried it seems like thesis won't pick this setups from wp-config

Comment: Do you observe this issue only in Thesis, or can you reproduce it when using, for example, Twenty Twelve or Twenty Eleven?

Comment: yes it seems like I have been changing the template and over there is working so I'm going to post this by thesis. Thanks for the feedbacks